# Incomprehensible differences by the use of case sensitivity

Tags: sql-server

Just set a case sensitive collate (CS) in order to get the strings with iso alpha-3 country code. All of them are capitalized.

Expected result:

| abc |
| --- |
| Athen GRE |
| Bern CHE |
| Berlin DEU |

My statement:

```sql
select abc 
from <db>.<scheme>.<table>
where abc like '% [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' collate Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Effective result:

| abc |
| --- |
| Ha Noi |
| Athen GRE |
| Bern CHE |

I get of course the correct result if I change the collate to
my statement:

```sql
select abc 
from <db>.<scheme>.<table>
where abc like '% [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```

My question is:
Should the first code with it's case sensitivity not divers from capitalized / lowercased? Or are there other conditions which deny it (e.g. overrunned by the db's ordering setting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the collation `Latin1_General_CS_AI` the characters are ordered  alphabetically, lowercase, uppercase. So `a`,`A`, `b`, `B`. You can see this in the below query:

```sql
SELECT V.C,
       CASE WHEN V.C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI LIKE '[A-B]' THEN 1 END
FROM (VALUES('A'),('B'),('a'),('b'))V(C)
ORDER BY V.C COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI ASC;
```

For `Latin1_General_100_BIN2`, however, they are in the order Uppercase, Alphabetically, Lowercase, Alphabetically, So `A`,`B`,...,`Z`, `a`, `b`. This can again be demonstrated as below:

```sql
SELECT V.C,
       CASE WHEN V.C COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 LIKE '[A-B]' THEN 1 END
FROM (VALUES('A'),('B'),('a'),('b'))V(C)
ORDER BY V.C COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 ASC;
```

Therefore, for your `LIKE` expression `[A-Z]` for the collation `Latin1_General_CS_AI` this would include the uppercase letters `A` through to `Z` *and* the lowercase letters `b` through to `z`.